# Why is my table blurry?

Tags: iphone, css, ios, mobile-safari

I am creating an HTML5 iPhone app when I came across a problem.  As you can see in the following picture, everything is blurry.

[image: blurry image]

Here is a normal page of the website:

[image: normal image]

I have tried using `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` in my css, but that doesn't make it look sharp and crisp like the second image.

How can I make the text (and table) sharp like the second image?

Comment: can you provide markup and/or link to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess, but it looks like Mobile Safari may be scaling your table to fit the screen. (If you can pinch-and-zoom your way to sharper and crisper text, that's a definite sign.) Try using the tag `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">` to set the scaling factor and see if it makes a difference.